# Default components in install4j

Tags: install4j

When my "installation components" screen runs (I'm in console mode, if it matters), I get the list of components to install, as expected.  However, the "default" response is to accept 2 of the components, even though their "Initially Selected for installation" option is false.

I want the user to be able to NOT select any of the optional components, and this isn't possible when it's defaulting to have some of them "Selected".

As far as I can tell, there are no varfiles being loaded.

Snippet from my install4j file:

---

```
<component name="A" id="527" customizedId="a" displayDescription="false" hideHelpButton="false" selected="false" changeable="true" downloadable="false" hidden="false">
  <description />
  <include all="false">
      <entry location=".i4j_external_314/a" fileType="regular" />
      <entry location=".i4j_external_2366/a" fileType="regular" />
      <entry location=".i4j_external_316/a" fileType="regular" />
      <entry location=".i4j_external_8155/a" fileType="regular" />
      <entry location=".i4j_external_318/a" fileType="regular" />
   </include>
   <dependencies />
</component>
<component name="B" id="528" customizedId="b" displayDescription="false" hideHelpButton="false" selected="false" changeable="true" downloadable="false" hidden="false">
   <description />
   <include all="false">
      <entry location=".i4j_external_316/b" fileType="regular" />
      <entry location=".i4j_external_8155/b" fileType="regular" />
      <entry location=".i4j_external_318/b" fileType="regular" />
   </include>
   <dependencies />
</component>
<component name="C" id="69" customizedId="c" displayDescription="false" hideHelpButton="false" selected="false" changeable="true" downloadable="false" hidden="false">
   <description />
   <include all="false">
      <entry location=".i4j_external_316/c" fileType="regular" />
      <entry location=".i4j_external_8155/c" fileType="regular" />
      <entry location=".i4j_external_318/c" fileType="regular" />
   </include>
   <dependencies />
```

Notice that in all 3 components, "selected" is false, and "changeable" is true.

When the installer runs, though, here is how it is presented:

```
    Which components should be installed?
    *: D
    *: E
    1: A
    2: B
    3: C
    Please enter a comma-separated list of the selected values or [Enter] for the default selection:
    [1,2]
```

(D and E are fine - they're set to "selected" and "not user changeable")

So, even though A and B are not "selected", they show up as a default.  Also notice that "C" is configured the same way as "A" and "B", yet doesn't show up in the default.

This is problematic, because I have no way to select "none" of the optional components.  I have to select at least 1 in order to not accept the default.

Thanks for any info - if you need more detail, I'd be happy to provide it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, but this would happen if you selected components A and B as dependencies for either component D or E. Do you use the latest version of install4j?

Comment: Latest version, yes (install4j Multi-Platform Edition 5.1.5 (build 5566)).

No dependencies set.

We originally had these 2 components set to "initially selected" and "user can change", but we realized that we wanted to be able to select "none", and we couldn't if it was configured that way.  So, I turned off "initially selected", but it doesn't seem to have changed anything.

Comment: I believe that I've gotten around this by adding a "run script" action that uses the api to force "selected" to "false" and "changeable" to "true".  A hack, but it gets me to where I need to be....

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'm sorry that I could not reproduce the problem.

Comment: Turns out that my hack is now causing problems with unattended installs, since it forces those components to "off", and there's no user input to allow them to be selected.  I'm hoping to find a way to determine whether it's an unattended install, and skip my hack for those....

Comment: context.isUnattended() will tell you that